# Create Rows in a Table using Javascript - adds too many cells...>

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a table on the fly... it almost works but I have an issue with the number of cell it adds.

My table has 8 columns (monday to Friday plus a total column at the end).

Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/kaf9qmh0/

As you can see, on row 1, it adds the 8 columns 3 times, then on row 2 it adds the columns twice and only on the last row does it only add 8 columns.

I suspect it is because Im using .append to add the rows as follows (line 105 in the fiddle) but my Javascript being very limited, Im not entirely sure how to make it stop add the columns to row 1 and 2.

```
$("#timesheetTable > tbody").append('<tr id="' + sourceTableRowID + '" data-tt-id="' + sourceTableRowID + '" class="timesheetRow row' + rowIndex2 + '"></tr>');
```

How can I make it to only add the cells (td) to the next row when it loops through rowIndex2 and increments it?

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a loop within a loop - which was causing the additional cells. Here's an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaf9qmh0/1/)**; and here's an extract of the modified code:

```
function createSampleRows() {
    var sourceTable = document.getElementById('activityTable');
    var sourceTableRows = sourceTable.rows.length;
    var targetTable = document.getElementById('timesheetTable');
    var rowindex;
    var targetTableColCount;

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        if (rowIndex == 1) {
           targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
           continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
        }
    }
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < (parseInt(sourceTableRows)-2); rowIndex++) {
        var sourceTableRowID = document.getElementsByClassName('activityTaskRow')[rowIndex].id;
        $("#timesheetTable > tbody").append('<tr id="' + sourceTableRowID + '" data-tt-id="' + sourceTableRowID + '" class="timesheetRow row' + rowIndex + '"></tr>');

    };

    // This loop was nested within the above loop
    for (x = 0; x < targetTableColCount; x++) {
        $("#timesheetTable > tbody > tr").append('<td id="' + x + '" style="width: 60px;height: 34px;" class=""></td>');
    };
};
```